# Eve framework: on_update hook

Tags: python, patch, insert-update, eve

I'm using Eve framework for REST API service.
Also I'm using DB hooks for doing some preprocessing before some actions:
http://python-eve.org/features.html#database-event-hooks

My question is:
Do I need to save into database my updated data in `on_update` hook or it's enough to update `original` item with `updates` like:

```
original.update(updates)
```

or it's needed to save this data somehow like this:

```
updated_item = original.update(updates)
# Fetch somehow requested resource from `resource_name` and do staff like this:
updated_resource = RequestedResource(updated_item)
updated_resource.commit()
```

Or there is some better/more EVE way?

Btw, I'm doing requests:

```
requests.patch("http://127.0.0.1:7000/users/2", headers=headers, json={"name": "John", "age": 30})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `on_update` hook, you just need to add/change the data you want changed on the `updates` dict received as parameter. It will already include the PATCH request body at this time and this is what will be sent to the update.

The `original` resource contains the resource being update and can be used for reference, but there's no use to change it.

Comment: So, when I send mentioned above request using `requests`, in `updates` I have `{"name": "John", "age": 30}` and in my `original` is original data. But when I'm getting the same item the second time, it contains  my old data(not updated)

Comment: What is HTTP response for the PATCH? Looks like it is getting some validation error, because this should work. Are you using/sending the etag header?

Comment: ('message: ', u'{"created_at": "2017-03-24T09:08:05", "_status": "OK", "_links": {"self": {"href": "users/2", "title": "User"}}, "updated_at": "2017-05-16T12:20:46", "id": 2}')
('status: ', 200)

Comment: If you try to request the resource after the PATCH using another tool like postman or curl, it works? Have you checked the data layer directly too see the changed data?

Comment: I've also sent a request using `curl`, one of changed fields is not updates (another one does not exist in response)

Comment: sorry, it works! I was trying to update `updated_at` field and it really didn't change.

Comment: Nice! Yeah, those meta fields `_created`, `_updated` are set by eve internally, and you can't set them to what you want.